# Microsoft and bpm

Tags: workflow, soa, esb, business-process-management

This question is for people who follow Microsoft's BPM offering and WF. I was looking at their website http://www.microsoft.com/soa/ but much of the info seems to be from 2007 as if nothing new is happening after that. I know that IBM and others are more stronger in the whole SOA, ESB area but is it that microsoft not paying too much attention to this area? or is it the market is not interested as much as they are in Java based offerings from other vendors who have consulting arms?

Also what do you think about the success of WF?

Comment: programming related how?

Comment: In response to "Mitch Wheat's" how is my question programming related; I think it is programming plus architecture related. After looking at WF, it seems to me that it is targeted at developers yet some people want to sell this as something that a business analyst or a normal user in a vertical domain can use to build their applications. I am a developer and I have to come up with a WF based solution for such domain users. I thought other developers might have looked at this WF/BPM topic from my perspective too so why not ask it here. Is there another better forum besides LinkedIn?

Comment: WF isn't just targeted at developers. Microsoft have cleverly developed Visio with the ability to design a workflow using entities from the "WF template", this can be imported into SharePoint Designer and easily converted into a working workflow to be run inside SharePoint. Also, with WF providing you with the ability to develop and host your own workflow designer, an organisation could potentially produce an internal product for their business analysts to use to develop workflows. I've not had a lot of experience with much else, but personally WF is a v.powerful tool.